# Methodologies used to speed up the process of creating and coding subforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My question is how programmers create, code, and organize subforms in general. By subforms, I mean those groups of controls that make up one UI experience. I'm looking for hints to help me better organize my form codes and to speed up the process of creating such forms. I swear to God, it takes way too long.

I've identified three broad groups of subform elements:
-Subforms have commands to do something.
-Subforms have data elements to carry out those commands.
-Subforms have states used to track things that aren't data.

The approach I use is to focus on what it takes to perform the commands which will determine which data elements are needed and how they should be validated.

Also, do programmers use check lists when creating forms?

p.s. I program as a hobby.

Comment: Use WPF :). I've always programmed WinForms and yes, it takes a lot of time and is tedious. I've switch to WPF and I've never looked back. Getting great forms is a lot easier with the flow layout and data binding.

Answer (score 3):

This is incredibly fuzzy.  There is however a red flag though, you seem to be talking about UI as a starting point instead of the end result.  That's a classic trap in winforms, the designer is rather good and makes it *way* too easy to endlessly tinker with form layouts.  You forever keep adding and removing controls and event handlers as your ideas about how the program is supposed to work evolve.

This is backward and indeed a huge time sink.  Effective design demands that you grab a piece of paper and focus on the structure of the program instead.  The starting point is the model, the M in the MVC pattern.  As you flesh out how the model should behave, it becomes obvious what kind of UI elements are necessary.  And what commands should be available to the user.

The V emerges.  Instead of jumping into the designer, sketch out what the view should look like.  On paper.  Make a rough draft of an organized way to present the data.  And what operations are available to the user to alter them.  Which selects the type of controls and the menus and buttons you'll need.  Once that congeals, you can very quickly design the form and add the C.  The event handlers that tie the UI to the model.

There's a very interesting tool available from Microsoft that helps you to avoid falling into this trap.  I love the idea of it, it intentionally makes the UI design step imperfect.  So you don't spend all that time pushing pixels around instead of focusing on the design of your program.  It draws UI designs in a paper-and-pencil fashion, there are no straight lines.  Incredibly effective not just for the programmer, also a "keep the customer focused and involved" fashion.  So that the customer doesn't fall in the same trap either, nagging about a control being off by one pixel.  It is called SketchFlow, link [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Sketchflow_Overview.aspx).  It is otherwise the exact same analogue of paper and pencil, but with a 'runs on my machine' flourish.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CAB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648747.aspx) I'm not sure you should use it, but the pattern will help you understand how to write your gui layer in a good way.